# why does my iCloud Drive tries to upload gigabytes of data daily?

Tags: mac, cloud-storage, icloud

Is there a way put iCloud Drive in verbose mode?
Right now my iCloud Drive wants to download 100 GB and upload 10 GB and I have literally no idea what it is doing.... Apple magic...

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there a way put iCloud Drive in verbose mode?

If by verbose mode you mean logging, then this Ask Different answer [View amount of time left when uploading files to iCloud](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/220832/118200) by [bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike) might help:

> Open terminal.app and issue the command:
>
> ```
> brctl log -w
> ```
>
> That will dump all sorts of iCloud sync data and debugging status -
>   most of which won't be relevant, but you can watch it over time to see
>   if any of the internal information allows you to calculate things or
>   just know that something is happening or has had an error.